# How to align multiple table in columns?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

[image]

I want to down the 3rd table so that align with others. There also a problem that the header of the 3rd table is joint together.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcolumntype{2}{D{.}{}{2.0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{GF(7)}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\begin{columns}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\noindent
 \begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{7}{2}}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
6 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Addition modulo $7$}
\end{column}

 \begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{7}{2}}
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 5\\
3 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4\\
4 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 3\\
5 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
6 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Multiplicative modulo $7$}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.2\linewidth}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{2}}
  w & -w & w^{-1}\\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & -\\
  1 & 6 & 1\\
  2 & 5 & 4\\
  3 & 4 & 5\\
  4 & 3 & 2\\
  5 & 2 & 3\\
  6 & 1 & 6\\
 \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Additive and Multiplicative inverse modulo $7$}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcolumntype{2}{D{.}{}{2.0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{GF(7)}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\begin{columns}[T]
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\noindent
 \begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{7}{2}}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
6 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Addition modulo $7$}
\end{column}

 \begin{column}{0.4\linewidth}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r|*{7}{2}}
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 5\\
3 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4\\
4 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 3\\
5 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
6 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Multiplicative modulo $7$}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.2\linewidth}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{r|*{2}{2}}
  w & -w & w^{-1}\\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & -\\
  1 & 6 & 1\\
  2 & 5 & 4\\
  3 & 4 & 5\\
  4 & 3 & 2\\
  5 & 2 & 3\\
  6 & 1 & 6\\
 \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Additive and Multiplicative inverse modulo $7$}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly was changed here to achieve the result? It is very unclear given the large amount of text.

Answer (score 3):

- I wouldn't mix `caption` package and `beamer`. beamer has its own `caption` mechanism
- in your case instead caption I rather use `\parbox` (name `Table` not seems to be informative
- naming column types with numbers is not a smart idea
- in your case you don't need the `dcolumn` package and `d` columns

  ```
  \documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
  \usetheme{Madrid}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{array}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{GF(7)}
  \begin{columns}[T]
      \footnotesize
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
  \begin{column}{0.35\linewidth}
   \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|*{7}{C}}
  + & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
  1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0\\
  2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1\\
  3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
  4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
  5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  6 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
  \end{tabular}\\[1ex]
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
                      Addition modulo $7$}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}{0.35\linewidth}
   \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|*{7}{C}}
  x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
  2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 5\\
  3 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4\\
  4 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 3\\
  5 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
  6 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
  \end{tabular}\\[1ex]
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
                      Multiplicative modulo $7$}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}{0.3\linewidth}
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}{r|CC}
    w & -w & w^{-1}\\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & -\\
    1 & 6 & 1\\
    2 & 5 & 4\\
    3 & 4 & 5\\
    4 & 3 & 2\\
    5 & 2 & 3\\
    6 & 1 & 6\\
   \end{tabular}\\[1ex]
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
                      Additive and Multiplicative inverse modulo $7$}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]